# Creating a always vertically centered div

Tags: html, css

I would like to center this responsive div in the middle on the page(always vertically centered) with the height being set to auto(the height at which the page is rendered or loaded)

I read about creating a ghost element and then positioning it against it? 
I'm not sure how to go about doing that so would be great if someone can guide me!

Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="responsive"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.responsive {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    background: #25BF59;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qSvAQ/55/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
.responsive {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    background: #25BF59;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="responsive"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: P.S if you don't mind me asking this too, do you have any idea on how to make the div blur/frosty? http://jsfiddle.net/jackcode/qSvAQ/59/

Comment: You want to blur green div ?

Comment: Yep, I found one "trick" being posted that overlays 1 blur image over the unblur one but that would work in responsive.. this does what I want https://webkit.org/blog/3632/introducing-backdrop-filters/ but seeing it being published in Aug last year I guess it will take sometime before it is implemented :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS `flexbox`, this would work without any width set on the `.responsive` div

```css
.container {
  height:1000px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.responsive {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #25BF59;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="responsive"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work because I would like the height to be auto(according to the device's height) :/ Found the solution above thanks for helping though!

Comment: This would work with any content within the .responsive div?? remove all heights and add content. It will work?

Answer (score 0):

I use the technique described by Nenad often. Another method, if you use Sass and you're not going to drop animations into the box would be:

```
$width: 2em;
$height: 2em;

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px; // some width;
    height: 500px; // some height;
}

.responsive {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - #{0.5*$height});
    left: calc(50% - #{0.5*$width});
    width: $width;
    height: $height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/qSvAQ/57/

This one is easy and only needs 3 lines of code:

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
```